# Renaming folder at runtime in Oozie or pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I am still new to Oozie and Pig. Can anyone please tell me if how can I rename a folder at runtime using Oozie or Pig.
I have a pig script that reads the data from a folder say Input and then write the output into Output folder. The flow is designed using Oozie. The next time i run the Oozie folder the Input folder should be deleted and the Output folder should be named as Input.

Thanks. Response awaited

Answer (score 2):

Oozie Fs (HDFS) action can be used to rename a directory.You can refer this [link](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.4_Fs_HDFS_action)

In the above link the following can you this portion in your workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app name="[WF-DEF-NAME]" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    ...
    <action name="[NODE-NAME]">
        <fs>
            <move source='[SOURCE-PATH]' target='[TARGET-PATH]'/>
        </fs>
        <ok to="[NODE-NAME]"/>
        <error to="[NODE-NAME]"/>
    </action>
    ...
</workflow-app>
```